# When streaming a file during a download, do you know the filesize?

Tags: java, file, streaming

When downloading large files, and you receive the file in chunks, is it possible to know the file size or that information is not in any type of header that you get back during the request/response?

Basically I would like to know if the file size is above a threshold before downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the file or stream that you are downloading - at one extreme if the chunks are part of a a continuos stream, like a live TV channel or a data analytics stream, then there is no real end and no size.

A more common example might be a video where many formats may have the size information in their metadata or header information.

For example an MP4 file will have the file size in the header information which should be the first part dowloaded, if the file has been prepared for streaming properly - MP4 files usually have the header at the end but when being prepared for streaming it is common best practice to move the header to the start.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the file or stream that you are downloading - at one extreme if the chunks are part of a a continuos stream, like a live TV channel or a data analytics stream, then there is no real end and no size.

A more common example might be a video where many formats may have the size information in their metadata or header information.

For example an MP4 'container' will have the size of a movie stream in the header information which should be in the first part dowloaded, if the file has been prepared for streaming properly - MP4 files usually have the header at the end but when being prepared for streaming it is common best practice to move the header to the start.